# Algorithm for Number similarity

Tags: c#, math, similarity

I'm looking for implementing an algorithm that can calculate the similarity of several numbers (0-100%).

This is one scenario for a movie database:
A user profile contains information about the user's movie preferences. That is stored using three attributes (How much I like Action, Drama or Cartoon) containing values between 1-10 (10 is that I like it a lot). On each movie you will find similar values (I.e. Terminator Action=10, Drama=5, Cartoon=1).

Now I would like to calculate how how much a user's preferences matches a movies preferences. What are your suggestions? (This is made in C#)

Regards

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Why 1-10 and not 0 to 10?  Surely for the Terminator, `Cartoon` would be 0 as 1 implies there was minimal cartoonage going on instead of, say, none ?:)  Unless you've seen a version of the Terminator I have missed in which case please divulge!

Comment: Isn't this simply the percentage difference between two values Math.Abs(A-B)/A*100?

Comment: Just wanted to type the same Plymouth :) +1

Comment: @Plymouth223 But if the movie has `Action == 10` and I like `Action == 1` (or the other way around) wouldn't that give a score of `90` or `900`? I'm sure in both cases, I wouldn't like the movie, no?

Comment: @Nolonar True, in that case it would require subtracting from 1 so (1-(Math.Abs(A-B)/A+B))*100.

Comment: @Plymouth223 I see, you're right. I was being too lazy to think it through, sorry :p

Comment: I tried yBees answer below. That seems similar to several other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static double SingleSimilarity(double x, double y)
{
    return (10.0 - Math.Abs(x - y)) * 10.0;
}

// 3 values of user preferences, 3 values of movie assessment
public static double Similarity(Tuple<double, double, double> user, Tuple<double, double, double> movie)
{
    return (SingleSimilarity(user.Item1, movie.Item1) + SingleSimilarity(user.Item2, movie.Item2) + SingleSimilarity(user.Item3, movie.Item3)) / 3.0;
}
```

Example:

```
var similarity = Similarity(Tuple.Create(10.0, 0.0, 5.0), Tuple.Create(0.0, 10.0, 5.0));
```

Or more generic method:

```
// 3 items (Action, Drama, Cartoon) each of which contain a value for user and movie
public static double Similarity(IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> list)
{
    return list.Sum(t => SingleSimilarity(t.Item1, t.Item2)) / list.Count();
}
```

And example:

```
var similarity = Similarity(new[] { Tuple.Create(10.0, 0.0), Tuple.Create(0.0, 10.0), Tuple.Create(5.0, 5.0) });
```

In such case the result will be 33.(3) and seems to be practice.

Comment: That was basically what I was looking for. Simple and easy to use, and it does the job. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
var metric = (movie.actionMetric - user.actionPreference) + (movie.dramaMetric - user.dramaPreference) + (moview.cartoonMetric - user.cartoonPreference)
```

This simple algorithm could be done within a database query (which is usually important) and spits out a lower number the higher a persons preference for it, you could also convert values to a percentage by `(1/metric) x 100`. You can also weight the algorithm fairly easily, say if you thought the "cartoon" metric was less important then drama or action:

```
var metric = (movie.actionMetric - user.actionPreference) + (movie.dramaMetric - user.dramaPreference) + 0.5 * (moview.cartoonMetric - user.cartoonPreference)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical solutions use different similarity measures (e.g. cosine, Pearson, Manhattan, etc.)  It's all covered beautifully in Toby Segaran's ["Programming Collective Intelligence"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325).